# Limit with a trigonometric function in the denominator

Tags: trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I had this simple looking limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{3^{(2^{x+1}-2)}-1}{\sqrt{1-\cos(x)}}$$

By some algebraic manipulation, I got here:

$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{9}\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{3^{2^{x+1}}-9}{|\sin(x)|}$$

But now, I am quite unable to move further, the exponential tower is making a lot of mess and I don't see any way out of here. Using derivatives is prohibited. I would really appreciate if anyone could point me the right way.

Comment: The limit does not exist because of the absolute value. It approaches $\pm \log 3 \cdot \log 2$ depending on the side.

Comment: @NinadMunshi So whenever an absolute value appears in the denominator, the limit does not exist? Or rather, how do I figure out the limits on either side of zero without using derivatives?

Comment: Not always. If the limit had been zero it wouldn't have mattered. Or if the limit was not approaching the cusp of the absolute value it also wouldn't have mattered.

Comment: I would follow the derivation of the limit $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}$$ to figure out how to do this one. It's just squeeze theorem at the right times with the right functions.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thank you for your answer. I am fairly new to limits, I only started them three days ago, so, please, excuse my lack of knowledge at the time. I found out that the limit as x approaches $0^+$ is about 2.153, which is not $log(3) \cdot log(2)$, so I am a little confused

Comment: I'm missing a factor of $2^{3/2}/3$ try that.

Comment: @ampersander The right-sided limit is $\sqrt(2)\log(9) \log(2)$.

Comment: @MarkViola Why? Plugging the equation into a graphing calculator produces a limit at $2.153$

Comment: And what is the approximation of $\sqrt{2} \log(9) \log(2)$?

Comment: @MarkViola oh, you see, in my country, $log$ means a logarithm with 10 as base. If we want to have $e$ as the base, we use $ln$. Sorry for the confusion, my bad.

Comment: Sure.  
No worry. ;-)